# Fullcalendar events have desaturated background color

Tags: css, colors, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I'm using fullCalendar's resource-timeline views and I have noticed that the event background colors are de-saturated.

I have used different ways to set their color, including setting all event background colors with CSS, and everything works (i.e. I have no problem changing the event colors), except that the colors lack saturation.

For example, using CSS like this:

```
div#calendar {
  background-color: red !important;
}
.fc-timeline-event {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

I would expect both the table background and the events to be saturated red. The background is, but the events are not. Checking with a color sampler shows that the background is `#ff0000`, but the cells are `#ff5952`, which corresponds to red saturated to 68%.

Strangely enough the browser inspector shows the computed background color as `#ff0000`.

Any ideas on how to achieve a display with fully saturated colors?

Comment: is this fullCalendar v3 or v4? And are you using a specific theme, or the default? P.S. a better way to set event colours is via the fullCalendar options: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-display - that way you can target events in all views, not just one, because the HTML and CSS is different across different views.

Comment: fullcalendar 3.9. I tried using event-display, but the result is the same. I have not changed the theme. And as said before, the browser inspector show the background color as saturated (#ff0000 in this case) but it displays desaturated. I thought there could be an element overlaying with alpha channel set to semi-transparent, but haven't seen one using the browser inspector.

Comment: I wasn't really suggesting event-display as a way to solve the problem, just as a better way, in general, to set event colours rather than using generic CSS rules. It was a separate remark.

Comment: Anyway I agree I was expecting some sort of alpha or opacity rule overlaying the event elements, but so far I haven't found anything...strange.

Answer (score 3):

I have my solution.

In your CSS style code, you put the code below

```
 .fc-bgevent {
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

The number 1 above can be changed to 0.9, 0.8 etc. It will replace the background event style.

And it works for me!

Comment: You solution does not work exactly as you say for me (maybe becaue I use the timeline view), but you put me on the right track, I found that there is an overlay with background color white and opacity 0.25. Changig the opacity of this overlay to 0 solves the problem. See my answer below.

Comment: @ChristerFernstrom Yes, I found what you found and I just give the solution directly :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of PrimeNg tag, solution is:

```
::ng-deep .fc .fc-bg-event {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar CSS contains a rule that overlays the calendar with white, opacity 25%. This causes the problem
:

```
.fc-event .fc-bg {
    z-index : 1;
    background; #fff;
    opacity: 0.25
 )
```

The opacity needs to be set to 0. So Added this in my own stylesheet:

```
.fc-event .fc-bg {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```